# What's the difference between 1 :| [2, 3, 4] and [1, 2, 3, 4] in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell

I'm learning Haskell, one of the best functional-programming language. I've got roadblocks during my studies with the list. As I figured out there are two possibilities to write a list - just wrap using `[]`. or use a `NonEmpty` list. What's the difference between these variants and what's better to use and why?

Comment: In short, `NonEmpty` will enforce *at compile time* that any lists you use aren't empty. That is useful if you have functions which simply can't cope sensibly with an empty list as input, and is much better than crashing at runtime. But on the other hand, empty lists crop up a lot in practice and often don't cause any problem at all - so it depends what your program wants to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[1,2,3,4]` is actually syntactic sugar for

```
Prelude> 1:2:3:4:[]
[1,2,3,4]
```

The `[]` type has two data constructors: `:` and `[]`. You use `:` to 'cons' a value to an existing list. The empty list `[]` is the base case, so in order to be able to create a finite list, you'll have to terminate the 'cons chain' with an empty list, as in the above example.

In other words, while `[1,2,3,4]` is one valid example of a list, so is `[]`. Lists can be empty.

As the name implies, `NonEmpty` can't be empty. It has *only one* data constructor: `:|`. Thus, the shortest list you can express using `NonEmpty` is a singleton list:

```
Prelude Data.List.NonEmpty> 1 :| []
1 :| []
```

While the right-hand side of `:|` *does* accept an empty list (`[]`), you *must* supply a value for the left-hand side (in the above example `1`). Thus, a `NonEmpty` list will always contain at least one element.

These properties are guaranteed at compile time, so if you need a non-empty list, use `NonEmpty`, and if you need a list that may be empty, use `[]`.

Comment: There's another formulation of nonempty lists that can be more appropriate for some purposes. `data NE a = Cons a (NE a) | Single a`. This representation uses one less word per list, which might matter if there are many such lists and most of them only have one element.